# tic-tac-toe: different output while using 1d-array over 2d- array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, tic-tac-toe, minmax

I am trying to build tic-tac-toe AI using min max algorithm. I was referring to this [post](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimax-algorithm-in-game-theory-set-3-tic-tac-toe-ai-finding-optimal-move/) from geekforgeeks for writing my code. But strangely when I'm using 1D array instead of 2D array by modifying the code as given below, I'm not getting the right output from findBestMove function. It is supposed to return index as 4, but it always returns 2. what am I doing wrong?

```
 function Move(x,y){
    this.row = x, 
    this.col = y;
};

const player = 'o', opponent = 'x';


const isMovesLeft = (board) => {
    for (let i = 0; i<3; i++)
        for (let j = 0; j<3; j++)
            if (board[i][j]=='_')
                return true;
    return false;
}

const isMovesLeft2 = (board) => {
    for (let i = 0; i<9; i++)
        if (board[i]=='_')
            return true;
    return false;
}

const evaluate = (b) =>{
    for (let row = 0; row<3; row++)
    {
        if (b[row][0]==b[row][1] &&
            b[row][1]==b[row][2])
        {
            if (b[row][0]==player)
                return +10;
            else if (b[row][0]==opponent)
                return -10;
        }
    }

    for (let col = 0; col<3; col++)
    {
        if (b[0][col]==b[1][col] &&
            b[1][col]==b[2][col])
        {
            if (b[0][col]==player)
                return +10;

            else if (b[0][col]==opponent)
                return -10;
        }
    }

    if (b[0][0]==b[1][1] && b[1][1]==b[2][2])
    {
        if (b[0][0]==player)
            return +10;
        else if (b[0][0]==opponent)
            return -10;
    }

    if (b[0][2]==b[1][1] && b[1][1]==b[2][0])
    {
        if (b[0][2]==player)
            return +10;
        else if (b[0][2]==opponent)
            return -10;
    }

    return 0;
}

const evaluate2 = (b) =>{
    for (let row = 0; row<3; row++)
    {
        if (b[row]==b[row+1] &&
            b[row+1]==b[row+2])
        {
            if (b[row]==player)
                return +10;
            else if (b[row]==opponent)
                return -10;
        }
    }

    for (let col = 0; col<3; col++)
    {
        if (b[col]==b[col+3] &&
            b[col+3]==b[col+6])
        {
            if (b[col]==player)
                return +10;

            else if (b[col]==opponent)
                return -10;
        }
    }

    if (b[0]==b[4] && b[4]==b[8])
    {
        if (b[0]==player)
            return +10;
        else if (b[0]==opponent)
            return -10;
    }

    if (b[2]==b[4] && b[4]==b[6])
    {
        if (b[2]==player)
            return +10;
        else if (b[2]==opponent)
            return -10;
    }

    return 0;
}

const minimax = (board , depth, isMax) => {
    let score = evaluate(board);

    if (score == 10)
        return score;

    if (score == -10)
        return score;

    if (isMovesLeft(board)==false)
        return 0;

    if (isMax)
    {
        let best = -1000;

        for (let i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for (let j = 0; j<3; j++)
            {
                if (board[i][j]=='_')
                {
                    board[i][j] = player;


                    best = Math.max( best,
                        minimax(board, depth+1, !isMax) );

                    board[i][j] = '_';
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }

    else
    {
        let best = 1000;

        // Traverse all cells
        for (let i = 0; i<3; i++)
        {
            for (let j = 0; j<3; j++)
            {

                if (board[i][j]=='_')
                {
                    board[i][j] = opponent;

                    best = Math.min(best,
                        minimax(board, depth+1, !isMax));
                    board[i][j] = '_';
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
}

const minimax2 = (board , depth, isMax) => {
    let score = evaluate2(board);

    if (score == 10)
        return score;

    if (score == -10)
        return score;

    if (isMovesLeft2(board)==false)
        return 0;

    if (isMax)
    {
        let best = -1000;

        for (let i = 0; i<9; i++)
        {
                if (board[i]=='_')
                {
                    board[i] = player;


                    best = Math.max( best,
                        minimax2(board, depth+1, !isMax) );

                    board[i] = '_';
                }

        }
        return best;
    }

    else
    {
        let best = 1000;

        for (let i = 0; i<9; i++)
        {


                if (board[i]=='_')
                {
                    board[i] = opponent;

                    best = Math.min(best,
                        minimax2(board, depth+1, !isMax));
                    board[i] = '_';
                }
        }
        return best;
    }
}

const findBestMove = (board) =>{
    let bestVal = -1000;
    let bestMove = new Move(-1,-1);

    for (let i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for (let j = 0; j<3; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j]=='_')
            {
                board[i][j] = player;

                let moveVal = minimax(board, 0, false);

                board[i][j] = '_';

                if (moveVal > bestVal)
                {
                    bestMove.row = i;
                    bestMove.col = j;
                    bestVal = moveVal;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return bestMove;
}

const findBestMove2 = (board) =>{
    let bestVal = -1000;
    let bestMove = -1;

    for (let i = 0; i<9; i++)
    {

            if (board[i]=='_')
            {
                board[i] = player;

                let moveVal = minimax2(board, 0, false);

                board[i]= '_';

                if (moveVal > bestVal)
                {
                    bestMove = i
                    bestVal = moveVal;
                }
            }

    }


    return bestMove;
}


const test = () => {
    const board = [['x','_','_'],
                   ['_','_','_'],
                   ['_','_','_']];
    const board2 = ['x','_','_',
                   '_','_','_',
                   '_','_','_'];
    console.log(findBestMove(board));
    console.log(findBestMove2(board2));
}

test();
```

When the test() is executed first function call returns best move as (1,1) but second function returns 2. It should be 4 ideally.

Comment: Sorry Suneeth, we cannot help looking for bugs. What error are you getting? What have you searched and tried so far?

Comment: it's hard to tell what's wrong with the code, without debugging it. You can try to use the debugger, by setting break points, watch values.

Comment: @R.Saban : description has been updated to better explain my problem. I couldn't find any difference between the two sets of functions apart from the type of array used. still they returns two different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function `evaluate2`, you loop like this:

```
for (let row = 0; row<3; row++)
```

You should loop like this

```
for (let row = 0; row<9; row+=3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is why people say 2 pairs of eyes are always better than one.